# Difference between initial containing block and viewport

Tags: css, w3c

Is there any difference between the two or are they the same? I think they refer to the same thing but in different contexts, but I am not sure so I ask here.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The initial containing block and the viewport, while related to each other, are two distinct concepts.

The viewport generally refers to the viewable area of a browser window in which a page is rendered on screen. The initial containing block is the logical area within the page in which the root element and everything else is rendered.

The dimensions of the initial containing block *are* based on those of the viewport (see [section 10.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details)), but when the content is no longer able to fit the viewport, the viewport is made scrollable so the user can continue to access the rest of the content. Additionally, the new [`vw`, `vh`, `vmin` and `vmax` units](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-3/#viewport-relative-lengths) are called viewport-percentage units, but they are also described as being relative to the size of the initial containing block.

Note that the definition of a viewport may vary depending on the device. For example, [the viewport of Safari on iOS is very different from that of a desktop browser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/appleapplications/reference/safariwebcontent/usingtheviewport/usingtheviewport.html).

Comment: Great answer. I just studied this things very hard, but there is a lot of terminology in this field. Right know I am reading PPK book the mobile web handbook and he talks a lot about this stuff. Now I get it.

Comment: Just one more question jsfiddle site has 4 viewports + the overall one, right ?

Comment: Each iframe has its own viewport, but on JSFiddle only the results pane actually lives in a viewport.

Comment: So, the inithial containing block = the canvas?

Comment: @user3790069: I would say that the initial containing block is rendered on the canvas.

Comment: But are dimensions of a canvas and dimensions of an initial containing block on the same page  indentical?

Comment: @user3790069: No, the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/intro.html#the-canvas) actually says that the canvas is infinite. The initial containing block is as large as it needs to be according to its contents, but it can theoretically expand as much as necessary to accommodate more contents, and thus occupy more of the canvas.

Comment: "The viewport generally refers to the viewable area of a browser window in which a page is rendered on screen. The initial containing block is the logical area within the page in which the root element and everything else is rendered.". To me those two sentences sound like they describe the same size in the end? What's the difference? Has it to do with scrolling? Is the viewport the visible area while the initial containing block is the total scrollable area?

Comment: @philmcole: The ICB's logical dimensions, determined mostly by the real dimensions of elements rendered on the page, can exceed those of the viewport, causing scrollbars. So, indeed, the ICB is the total scrollable area. This is usually the case with desktop browsers, as the viewport is implemented a bit differently on mobile (at least, last I recall anyway). On desktop, the viewport dimensions are pretty much the dimensions of the frame of the browser window where a webpage is visible.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But weirdly according to 10.1 of [CSS2](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/visudet.html#containing-block-details) the size is the same. "For continuous media, [the initial containing block] has the dimensions of the viewport.". So they actually do have the same size if you forget about paged layout. This also means, that the viewport-percentage units could have been defined as well with respect to the viewport's size (for continuous media at least).

Comment: @philmcole: Dammit, I forgot. I haven't brushed up on this stuff in a while. Hmm...

Comment: But then again, [css-values-4](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values-4/#viewport-percentage-lengths) contradicts CSS2 by saying the size of the viewport and the ICB are different. "Note that the initial containing block’s size is affected by the presence of scrollbars on the viewport.". The spec is really far from consistent...

Comment: @philmcole: I was aware of what CSS2 originally said, but not the updated text in css-values-4. So L4 agrees with me, eh? The plot thickens.