# Can I change the initial containing block size?

Tags: html, css, viewport-units

I am using `vh` and `vw` units to style certain elements of a page. It's all working well when the initial containing block and viewport are of the same size. This is what it says in the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-values/#viewport-relative-lengths):

> The viewport-percentage lengths are relative to the size of the initial containing block.

But this way `vh` and `vw` are not the size I want, so how can I change the size of the initial containing block so that my `vh` and `vw` units are relative to this new size?

Comment: Please show what you have tried already.  Setting an element size is simple and can be done with css width and height, but without knowing what you are sizing and more info there is no real answer to your question.

Comment: If you mean an element that is not the viewport...that's not what `vh/vw` means....these are **viewport units**.

Comment: you cannot change *the initial containing block*

Comment: Why not just use a percentage if you want it relative to the parent?  Or are you just asking how to resize the browser?

Comment: @Pete Because my page is already styled in `vh` and `vw` units, and it's looking OK. But I wan't to fix the viewport size past the certain screen width, so that my design doesn't stretch.

Comment: Use a media query at that point to change the units to px?

Comment: @Pete On it right now ( : Thanks.

Comment: "relative to this new size" what new size?

Comment: @TylerH The one I wanted to set myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of the initial containing block is always the same as that of the viewport. You can't change this size (except via the viewport meta tag, which probably isn't what you're looking for).

> @Pete Because my page is already styled in vh and vw units, and it's looking OK. But I wan't to fix the viewport size past the certain screen width, so that my design doesn't stretch.

What you want to do is write a media query for when the screen exceeds a certain width, then replace all your dimensions that use viewport units with your desired values.

Comment: Such a bummer. Yes, I've already tried it via the viewport meta tag, but apparently that doesn't work for desktop browsers.

Comment: "You're looking for a media query". I know, but I was just hoping this could be solved more easily. I'm on it now. Thanks!

Comment: How is it possible the sizes of the initial containing block amount to those of the viewport whereas the ICB's descendants may be larger than viewport's sizes? (`:root { height: 200vh; }`) In this case does it mean a descendant box overflows the ICB?

Comment: @Ilya Loskutov: The spec appears to be kind of inconsistent as to whether the ICB's dimensions can resize with the content, or if it always matches the viewport size (in which case yes, descendant boxes could overflow it). See the comments under [this other answer I posted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25650241/difference-between-initial-containing-block-and-viewport/25650449#25650449).